# Assembling Custom PDFs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gravityforms

I have been approached by a client to build a WordPress website that has a form that allows the user to select multiple exercises from a list. When the user clicks "Submit", the client wants the user to be emailed a PDF detailing those specific exercises. Is there a way to do this using Gravity Forms or Typeform?

Comment: A two second search found this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-pdf-extended/ — 1) Google 2) Ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a custom function that hooks onto the submission of the form which would create the PDF for you.

Take a look at https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Hope this helps :)